# UIScrollview, it can be dragged down so far that you can see its parent view behind it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I've set

```
 scrollview.bounces = NO;
```

and I cannot find anything else that maybe relevant. When the scrollview is at the top or botton of the view and i try and scroll it further, it slides down and I can see the parent view behind it.

Is there something that can be done to stop this behavious?

Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 relevant parts to the `UIScrollView` in this case. The scroll view contents and the scroll view.

Your scrollview doesn't move on a scroll/drag. The `CGRect` frame stays constant.
Your scrollview contents move up and down on scroll/drag.

It sounds like the contents of your scroll view have an opaque background which hides the stuff behind the scrollview. But when you go beyond the bounds of the contents, you are see what is behind the scroll view because the scrollview itself has a transparent background.

Solution: Give your `UIScrollView` a opaque background.

Answer (score 0):

Make your parent view alpha to zero. That will solve your problem and you don't have to do any  changes on UIScrollView.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
```